# angular form can't get hidden value

Tags: angular

I'm stuck trying to get hidden dynamic data from my form to my component on angular.

```
<form (submit)= "onLike()"> 
  <input type="hidden" name=likeQuote [(ngModel)]=likeQuote  value ="anything" style="display: none;"/>
  <input type="submit" value = "Like">
</form>
```

I also try other method such as styling the form to non-display.

```
  <input type="text" name=likeQuote [(ngModel)] = likeQuote value= {{ quote._id}} style= "display:none;">
```

However, angular just won't pick it up.

Comment: Provide more and code and identify a defined question. Right now, I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm trying to submit the hidden input value({{quote._id}}) to my angular component, but my component can't pick the hidden input.

Comment: Well start using `input type="text"`, because you're already setting its display property to none.

Comment: for starters, you could format your code correctly `[name]="likeQuote" [(ngModel)]="likeQuote"` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuuwsc

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `value` with a `ngModel`, change to this to set a default value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="likeQuote" [(ngModel)]="likeQuote" style="display: none;"/>
```

Component:

```
public likeQuote = 'Hello world';
```

Then you can access its value through `likeQuote`.

Comment: I see what you did, but some of the value is dynamic values that are pulled from the backend. Is there anyway to put hidden value in forms on angular?

Comment: You would just do `this.likeQuote = 'New value'`, I don't think hidden property matters.

Comment: I can't do that, because some of the value is pull from the database. I can't just declare a value in my component.

Comment: Yes you can.. Fetch it in the component and then set the class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [hidden angular property](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

> [hidden]="myCondition"

You set it to true so it's always hidden and you still have it in the DOM, accessible to Angular. You have the possibility to add some logic later on if needed.

```
<form (submit)= "onLike()"> 
  <input type="input" [hidden]="true" name=likeQuote [(ngModel)]=likeQuote  value ="anything" />
  <input type="submit" value = "Like">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for replying in such a timely manner. I'm new in general, and I'm having a hard time using the correct syntax to make myself clear. But the way I solve my problem is just using button instead of form.

```
<button type="button" (click)="onLike(quote._id)">Like</button>
```

It's not pretty, but I manage to my data to the component and the backend. Thank you.